# pip installs away from PYTHONPATH

Tags: homebrew, python

On a Mac OSX 10.11.6 (El Capitan) I have a fresh Homebrew installation of python 2.7

```
$ which python2
/usr/local/bin/python2

$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.14
```

and I am trying to install the `matplotlib` package using pip2:

```
$ pip2 install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-2.1.1-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Collecting six>=1.10 (from matplotlib)
  Using cached six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting backports.functools-lru-cache (from matplotlib)
  Using cached backports.functools_lru_cache-1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz (from matplotlib)
  Using cached pytz-2017.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 (from matplotlib)
  Using cached pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.0 (from matplotlib)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting subprocess32 (from matplotlib)
Collecting cycler>=0.10 (from matplotlib)
  Using cached cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, backports.functools-lru-cache, pytz, pyparsing, python-dateutil, subprocess32, cycler, matplotlib
Successfully installed backports.functools-lru-cache-1.4 cycler-0.10.0 matplotlib-2.1.1 pyparsing-2.2.0 python-dateutil-2.6.1 pytz-2017.3 six-1.11.0 subprocess32-3.2.7
```

Although `matplotlib` is reportedly installed, this is not seen upon calling `pip2 list`:

```
$ pip2 list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
nose (1.3.7)
numpy (1.13.3)
pip (9.0.1)
scipy (1.0.0)
setuptools (36.5.0)
wheel (0.30.0)
```

and in fact:

```
$ python2 -c 'import matplotlib'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

It turns out that the directory where pip2 installed into is `~/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`. For python2 to load it as a module I could include this latter path in my `$PYTHONPATH` variable, however I would prefer not to rely on the directory `~/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` as my python installation is rather messy in that location (there is stuff that was put there without Homebrew) and I would hope to rely on Homebrew alone for the moment.

How can I tell `pip` that the default directory for brewed modules is the same as `PYTHONPATH`? Hoping that it would do the trick.

Trying to refer to this: 
https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Homebrew-and-Python.md#site-packages-and-the-pythonpath
but I am not sure I am quite getting at it.
Thx.

Comment: Where is pip2 and how was it installed? Is matplotlib also a Homebrew package - if so use that

Comment: /usr/local/bin/pip2

Comment: Pip2 was part of the Homebrew installation of python. Matplotlib not available via Homebrew as we speak.